# What is the default value for a binary column?

Tags: mysql, binary, passwords, default

What is the default value for a binary column? Should it be specified when the column is "NOT NULL"? And how should it be specified?

I ask the above because after increasing the size of my password column from `binary(32) NOT NULL` to `binary(60) NOT NULL`, all the logins failed. The hex of all the passwords are now zero-padded like this to fill up the entire column:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| hex(password)                                                                 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| B41DF3CA2BFB639FA62DA56DF475EBC1E5C054E6CF00000000000000000000000000000000000 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What should be the proper way of handling the expansion of a binary password column?

Comment: I mean never did this, but what do you expect? But I found this here: [For binary strings, all characters are significant in comparisons, including trailing spaces:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-collations.html). So even if it would be nothing it would not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL `BINARY` is fixed length, which is why the value is padded.  You probably want `VARBINARY(60)` which behaves like `VARCHAR` in that it does not pad on the right.